# Unable to enter value in text box using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate updating my number in Naukri.com. I was able to get the value from the text box, but unable to update the value. This is what I tried:

```
WebElement mobileNo = driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")); 
if(mobileNo.getAttribute("value").equals("9912345678"))
{
    System.out.println("Test Ran");
    mobileNo.clear();
    mobileNo.sendKeys("+91 9912345678");
}
else if(mobileNo.getAttribute("value").equals("+91 1234567891"))
{
    mobileNo.clear();
    mobileNo.sendKeys("9912345678");
}
System.out.println("Test Ran");
```

Comment: What is the exception? And, what exactly happening?

Comment: exception -> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

...........
I am able to get the value from the webelement and print in console. but, unable to enter the value I want into the webelement.

Comment: I cannot find the element with id *nokia* on *Naukri.com*. Am I missing something?

Comment: text 'mobile' itself is an element.

Comment: Steps to replicate my issue: Open Naukri.com -> Edit profile -> try to automate editing mobile number using selenium

Comment: Do I need to log in?

Comment: Yes. login and click on Edit profile. there you could see mobile number text box. that is where i am trying automate.

Comment: .....................................

Answer (score 1):

The reason being the phone number is set to the *value* attribute and only way that I know to update that is to use JavaScript with Selenium. You can easily use the following JavaScript and JQuery to simply update the phone number.

```
WebElement mobileNo = driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")); 
JavascriptExecutor jscript = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

if(mobileNo.getAttribute("value").equals("9912345678"))
{
    System.out.println("Test Ran");
    jscript.executeScript("$('#mobile').attr('value','+91 9912345678')");

}
else if(mobileNo.getAttribute("value").equals("+91 9944991706"))
{
    jscript.executeScript("$('#mobile').attr('value','9912345678')");
}
System.out.println("Test Ran");
```

Comment: hi Saifer, I tried the one you posted and getting following implementaion error 'The method executeScript(String) is undefined for the type JavaScriptExecutor' . Can you please suggest me the solution?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. Corrected just  now. try it again